# Importing javascript into React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How would I import this https://codepen.io/aecend/pen/WbONyK javascript fluid simulation into a react component?

```
<h1>Click and drag!</h1>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this, for example

1. Create a .js (javascript file) which houses the script
2. Include the script in a  tag in your index.html
3. Execute it on the window object within the script

I created a quick codesandbox.. I had to make some edits on the variable declarations in the fluidSim.js file.

[See here](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-water-9d82s?file=/public/scripts/fluidSim.js)

Wait about 30s and click the refresh on the inner browser window once loaded

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much for helping me out with this!

Comment: You are welcome. Just a reminder of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)